# How to strip unwanted characters?

Tags: php, character-encoding

When i m inserting some text into 'text' field in database, it automatically generates some unwanted characters like `Â`

i m using `charset= iso-8859-1`

how to solve this?

Comment: Either change your encoding or use a regex replacement to keep the characters that you want.

Comment: when u r voting down..kindly tell the reason first.

Comment: You're getting down voted because you didn't provide much information. Can you show the code doing the insert, and give more background?

Answer (score 1):

Change CHARSET=ISO-8859-1 to **CHARSET=UTF-8**

read more here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Comment: same problem persists with UTF-8

Comment: Change the document format you coding in, in notepad++ it's format in the menu bar then choose "code in UTF-8"